# How to get URL-friendly string in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for a way to get URL friendly strings. I'm handling properly the special characters (?;:!?./§*$^¨£µ...)

However I'm struggling with latin letters that have some accents like : ÄÊÍÕàùã...

For a string like

## ÄÊÍÕABCDEàùã

I'm expecting

## AEIOABCDEaua

I tried :

```
SELECT CONVERT('ÄÊÍÕABCDEàùã', 'US7ASCII', 'AL32UTF8') FROM DUAL;
```

But it returns

```
AEI?ABCDEau?
```

It's ignoring some of the characters (Õ,ã). I tried all character sets detailed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm#SQLRF00620)  but none of them converted all the string characters properly.

Is there a way to convert all latin letters to their corresponding in simple form please ?

Thanks
Cheers,

Comment: What do you mean by "URL-friendly"? Perhaps you mean [UTL_I18N.ESCAPE_REFERENCE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_i18n.htm#ARPLS71120)

Comment: Nowadays special characters like `ÄÊÍÕABCDEàùã` are permitted in URL

Comment: I agree with @Wernfied Domscheit regarding what consists of an acceptable URL. With regard to removing accents, I saw this Oracle Forum which appears to want to do something similar ,https://community.oracle.com/thread/1117030.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer :

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort('ÄÊÍÕABCDEàùã', 'nls_sort=binary_ai'))) from dual
```

returns :

```
aeioabcdeaua
```

Comment: Hi, I assume your answer is informed from MichaelS' answer from the Oracle Forum I cited above. I think some attribution is needed here.